# Text content does not match server-rendered HTML for translation using i18n

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering, i18next

i have integrated i18n with my nextjs project
i have this folder structure for my locales (if its relevent)  `public/locales/en/translation.json` and `public/locales/fr/translation.json`

The error i get is

> Uncaught Error: Text content does not match server-rendered HTML.
> Warning: Text content did not match. Server: "about" Client: "About
> us"

this is my language switcher

```
import { withTranslation } from "next-i18next";
const LanguageSwitcher = ({ i18n }) => {
  const changeLanguage = (locale) => {
    console.log("LOCALE+++++++++++++>", locale);
    i18n.changeLanguage(locale);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => changeLanguage("en")}>English</button>
      <button onClick={() => changeLanguage("fr")}>French</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default withTranslation()(LanguageSwitcher);
```

and this is my component in which i am using multi language

```
import { useTranslation } from "next-i18next";
import LanguageSwitcher from "./LanguageSwitcher";

function HeaderNav() {
  const { t } = useTranslation("translation");
 <LanguageSwitcher />
        <Typography>{t("about")}</Typography>
export default HeaderNav;
```

this is my Layout for whole application

```
"use client";
import "./globals.css";
import HeaderNav from "./components/headerNav";
import { Providers } from "./GlobalRedux/provider";
import { usePathname } from "next/navigation";
import { Raleway } from "next/font/google";
import { CurrencyProvider } from "./context/CurrencyContext";
import "./i18n";
import { appWithTranslation } from "next-i18next";

const raleway = Raleway({ subsets: ["latin"] });

function RootLayout({ children }) {
  const pathname = usePathname();

  if (pathname.includes("/login")) return children;
  if (pathname.includes("/register")) return children;
  if (pathname.includes("/resetpassword")) return children;
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={raleway.className}>
        <CurrencyProvider>
          <Providers>
            <HeaderNav />

            {children}
          </Providers>
        </CurrencyProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
export default appWithTranslation(RootLayout);
```

this is my next.config.js

```
// next.config.js
const { i18n } = require("./next-i18next.config");

const nextConfig = {
  distDir: "build",
  i18n,
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

this is my i18n.js

```
 // Example i18n initialization
    import i18n from "i18next";
    import { initReactI18next } from "react-i18next";
    import Backend from "i18next-http-backend";
    import LanguageDetector from "i18next-browser-languagedetector";
    
    i18n
      .use(Backend)
      .use(LanguageDetector)
      .use(initReactI18next)
      .init({
        fallbackLng: "en",
        interpolation: {
          escapeValue: false,
        },
      });
    
    export default i18n;
```

this is my next-i18next.config.js

```
 // next-i18next.config.js
    const { i18n } = require("next-i18next");
    
    module.exports = {
      i18n,
      locales: ["en", "fr"], // Add more locales as needed
      defaultLocale: "en",
      fallbackLng: "en",
      // Other configuration options can go here
    };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass resources in i18n configurations

```
const resources = {
  en: {
    translation: require("../../public/locales/en/translation.json"),
  },
  fr: {
    translation: require("../../public/locales/fr/translation.json"),
  },
};
```

Comment: yeah thats what i was thinking it solved the issue

Answer (score 1):

well i still dont know how the error is gone but i fixed the problem
i updated my **i18n.js** file heres the solution , if  anyone knows how the error is solved please do tell

```
import i18n from "i18next";
import { initReactI18next } from "react-i18next";
import Backend from "i18next-http-backend";
import LanguageDetector from "i18next-browser-languagedetector";

const resources = {
  en: {
    translation: require("../../public/locales/en/translation.json"),
  },
  fr: {
    translation: require("../../public/locales/fr/translation.json"),
  },
};
i18n
  .use(Backend)
  .use(initReactI18next)
  .init({
    resources,
    fallbackLng: "en",
    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false,
    },
  });

export default i18n;
```